# problem with wavesurfer-js intract with preloaded peaks

Tags: javascript, wavesurfer.js

There was a problem for me that I couldn't find the answer to

Although I set the value of "interact" to "true", it clicks on the sound wave play from the beginning

my constructor:

```
audioContext: audiocontext,
container: soundWaveContainers[index],
waveColor: "#999",
progressColor: "#00ffaf",
cursorColor: "#999",
height: 52,
mediaType: "audio",
normalize: false,
hideScrollbar: false,
mediaControls: true,
interact: true,
backend: "MediaElement",
```

load:

```
wavesurfer.load(streamURL, soundPeaks);
```